# Symfony findAll() returns wrong type of resultset

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using php symfony framework. I want to fetch all rows from the user table. That's why I have written

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
$users = $repository->findAll();
```

But it array returns a strange type of array.

```
Array ( 
            [0] => AppBundle\Entity\User Object ( [id:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 1 [roll:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 1 [name:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => kumar [password:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 123456 ) 
            [1] => AppBundle\Entity\User Object ( [id:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 2 [roll:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 2 [name:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => arpan [password:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 1234 ) 
            [2] => AppBundle\Entity\User Object ( [id:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 3 [roll:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 3 [name:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => Bumba [password:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => abcd ) 
        )
```

now if I try to return ***new Response(json_encode($users))*** it returns [{},{},{}]. Help me.

Comment: You should read about doctrine, it's object oriented way to work with databases. In all cases it will return the object of model, not value.

Answer (score 4):

What it's returning is an array of objects. Generally this is what you want as its automatically bound/hydrating all the entities you've created, so you can now call `$result->getFoo()` .

However as you appear to want a json result you should call `->getArrayResult()` rather than `->findAll()`

Like this:

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('User entity namespace') // probably AppBundle/Entity/User
        ->createQueryBuilder('u') 
        ->getQuery(); 
 $result = $query->getArrayResult();
```

I **highly** advice you read the documentation from top to bottom about 10 times, especially the Symfony  & Doctrine section https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Comment: If I use getArrayesult instead of findAll then it's giving BadMethodCallException
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
Undefined method 'getArrayResult'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!